# Meteor: How to make a helper function reactive?

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to get a helper to re-run and return the updated collection whenever this collection is updated.

For example:

```
Template.imagegallery.myimages = function() {

   return Images.find({owner: Meteor.userId()}).fetch(); 

}
```

When I add data to the Images via a Meteor.call on the server side, my collection updates locally on the client, but the helper function does not re-run and the images don't update.....

any idea what i need to do to put the return collection from the helper object into a re-active context?

Comment: First, you probably don't need to use `fetch`. If you're planning to use this helper along with `witch` then returning a cursor is good enough. Also, can you show us the part of the code where you're calling this helper?

Comment: Why not creating a publication that does this instead? Publications are reactive by essence. I second apendua on the code thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a cursor instead of a array:

Helper:

```
Template.imagegallery.myimages = function() {
   return Images.find({owner: Meteor.userId()});
}
```

Template:

```
<template name="imagegallery">
     {{#each myimages}}
           !!!DOSTUFF!!!
     {{/each}}
</template>
```

Fetch breaks reactivity in almost all cases. Because when you use fetch the Blaze only receives a array. So Blaze never creates the dependencies required for reactivity because it doesn't know that is data coming from a collection as that information is lost when you use fetch.

*Blaze is meteor's templating system